# How to learn linux system programming by reading man pages?

Tags: linux, systems-programming

I read `man creat`, `man open` and `man close` & i find man pages the best source to learn linux.

But i need a read map, i want to know a list of man pages that gives the high level overview and then subsections that dive into the details.

Please advise.

Comment: & yes i did google this before posting the question :)

Comment: `cd /usr/share/man2` followed by `ls`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Try `man man`. It tells you the manual sections. Then, read an entire section that pertains to programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `man -k intro` gives a list including the following:

```
intro (1)            - introduction to user commands
intro (2)            - introduction to system calls
intro (3)            - introduction to library functions
intro (4)            - introduction to special files
intro (5)            - introduction to file formats and filesystems
intro (6)            - introduction to games
intro (7)            - introduction to overview and miscellany section
intro (8)            - introduction to administration and privileged commands
```

Each one can be read by `man intro.N` (N being 1-8), these intro pages looks like the begining of chapters in the man documentation.